# How do you test a redux connected react component by exporting it as a PureComponent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, enzyme

I've been looking for a solution that I know works but syntax is tripping me up.
Here's the scenario:

You have a redux connected component that is exported like so:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(componentToExport);
```

You need to test that component and not see this error in Enzyme:

```
Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(componentToExport)"
```

The solution looks something like the following.

At the bottom of the component being tested you have:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(componentToExport);
export default componentToExport as PureComponentToExport
```

I've tried using:

```
import from React, { PureComponent }
```

and then creating the component with

```
extends PureComponent
```

but that's not working as expected. Enzyme should really have this covered in the docs :/

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
I don't want to include an external library, or pass the store into the component being tested etc. I'd like to be able to use this syntax that I've seen work before.

thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you just `export componentToExport`?

Comment: That is it exactly. Thank u. If you'd like to get the accepted answer - feel free to answer. Otherwise I will self answer. Using pure is a version of the same thing I think. Using an additional export is so minimal. I love it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';


export class YourComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ChildComponent/>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    state,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
    yourActionsGoHere,
    },
    dispatch
  );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent);
```

In your Enzyme test you'll want:

```
import { YourComponent } from '../YourComponent';
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to do it is to also export the unconnected component, e.g. by adding `export` to its definition or by using an explicit export:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent);
export { YourComponent }; // export must contain braces or else it will give an error
```

And then import it in your test with a named import like so

```
import { YourComponent } from '../YourComponent';
```

There's some more information about testing connected components in the [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components).

Comment: There's a little bit more to it than this actually:
In the class declaration you want: 
export class YourComponent extends Component
then at the end of the file you'll have:
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent);
And last but not least - in the test where you're importing you have to import YourComponent as an object so: 
import { YourComponent } from '../YourComponent"
If you make these edits I'll delete the comment and mark your answer accepted - otherwise I'll self answer :)

Comment: Made some changes. The default export is not relevant for testing the unconnected component, so I left it out.

Comment: I tried using the export on it's own but that did not work.

Comment: Did you put it after the class definition? (classes are not hoisted)

Comment: export class YourComponent extends Component
I tried at EOF but it did not work.
I think it's good to include the connected export because the question is specifically asking how a component that is connected to redux gets set up, and tested without redux issues.

Comment: That should work if it's followed by the actual class definition, i.e. `export class YourComponent extends Component {...}`. Otherwise I'm not sure what you mean with export on it's own.

Comment: Dude. That is for brevity.